# How to suppress newline in natbib refererences by editing .bst files

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle, custom-bib, bst

I would like to suppress the newline between different citations in the references. Typically, the references look like this:

```
[1] aaa. 
[2] bbb.
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
[1] aaa. [2] bbb.
```

This should be a relatively straightforward fix, but after extensive searches, there have been no solutions that work. I am using the ieeetr natbib style file that has already been edited.

I see an `output.bibitem` function, which reads

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

which I have tried editing by removing the newline$ to read

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ 
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

However, this does not change anything.

Any solutions? I am *not* looking for a solution that requires biblatex, but rather one that implores the dark arts to edit the .bst file directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer takes the approach of modifying `\bibitem`, rather than editing the `.bst` file.

The newlines are caused by the use of `\item` within `\bibitem`, or in Natbib actually the helper macro `\@lbibitem`. You can modify the code to remove `\item`. This can be done with the `\patchcmd` macro from the `etoolbox` package.

Within the item label, Natbib performs some administration to link the cite key to the correct number. This part of the code should be kept after the modification. Concretely, change the code from

```
\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]
```

to

```
\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}\space
```

With `\patchcmd`:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}\space}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This already works, but the whole paragraph is indented. To correct for this you can reduce `\labelsep`:

```
\setlength{\labelsep}{-1em}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}{\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}\space}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{manual-minimal,misc-full,misc-minimal}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\setlength{\labelsep}{-1em}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this modification results in a warning: *Package natbib Warning: Empty 'thebibliography' environment on input line 24.* This is because there is still an enumerate environment but there are no more items in it. To implement this change in a cleaner way you should also remove the environment and the check that triggers this warning - however for the result it does not seem to have an adverse effect.

Comment: That certainly accomplishes the objective and is neater than changing the .bst file. However, it appears to add an indent to the references - any reason for this and how to overcome it?

Comment: @Sid Changing `\labelsep` is supposed to remove the indent, as mentioned in the answer. Did you put the statement in the correct position? What happens if you change the value of `-1em` to something else? If this does not work in your case then you need to show a minimal working example of your actual document that demonstrates the indent issue, in order for me or other people on the site to reproduce the problem and try to solve it.

Comment: It does work, though it affects any other enumerated or itemized lists. I guess these can be locally overridden.

Comment: @Sid the idea is that you put the line changing `\labelsep` directly above the `\bibliography` statement, in that way lists before the bibliography are not affected (because the value hasn't been changed yet, LaTeX processes the input top to bottom). Presumably the bibliography is the final section of the document so there is nothing afterwards to be affected by the change. Of course if there is an Appendix or something else afterwards then you can change the labelsep again to the original value.